# print mathematical expression in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having problem writing the title for my plot. There is a for loop that generate N plots and each plot should have a specific title. For example in one of the loops, title is 100^{2.4}_{5.6}. I have the following code but it only put the first digit of upper/lower value.

```
a=[100,200,300]
b=[2.4,3.5,6.7]
c=[5.6,1.3,4.2]
for i in plots:

    plt.title(r"${}^{}_{}$".format(a[i],b[i],c[i]))
```

Which in this example a[1]=100, b[1]=2.4, c[1]=5.6. What this code outputs is 100^{2}.4_{5}.6!!!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify the problem, or provide an [mcve]. ``r"${}^{}_{}$".format(a[i],b[i],c[i])`` for ``i=0`` outputs ``'$300^6.7_4.2$'``, and similarly well-formed strings for other values of ``i``. What output do you desire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{}` from `.format` interferes with the `{}` from LaTeX.

Using the old formatting, you get the expected result:

```
plt.title(r"$%d^{%.1f}_{%.1f}$" %(a[i], b[i], c[i]))
```

Basically things like `"$x_12$"` create something that looks like `"$x_1 2$"` so you need to use brackets for any sub/superscript that uses more than one character.

Answer (score 2):

What you want can be done using the *f* strings formatting as:

```
a = [100, 2.4, 5.6]
plt.title(f"${a[0]}^{ {a[1]} }_{ {a[2]} }$")
# Text(0.5, 1.0, '$100^{2.4}_{5.6}$')
```

In this example I have taken a hypotetical list `a` but obviously it works for any number you use.

Comment: I have edited the answer, it also works without triple quotes. I was using them before to avoid potential quotation errors.